# Rails unable to generate model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to learn rails by following the tutorial [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). However when I got to [the section on creating the model](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-the-article-model) and ran this command:

```
bin/rails generate model Article title:string text:text
```

I got this error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:152:in `serve': undefined method `cleanup!' for ActionDispatch::Reloader:Class (NoMethodError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

This is my second go through so I know I have followed all the steps. Any idea where I might look for the solution or know what the solution is?
This really has me stuck.

Versions:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
- gem 2.6.12
- rails 5.1.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/486), can you run `spring stop` and try to run your command again?

Comment: That fixed it but do not know why.

Comment: Spring show some problems from time to time. I don't know why either, but every time it complains about something with me I kill it and restart, and everything works out again.

Answer (score 3):

Restarting worked for me too, but I needed to do it every-time. Instead, I upgraded to to the latest version of spring (2.0.2) in my gemfile. This fixed it.